# ¿COMO PUEDO CREAR LA SIGUIENTE BASE DE DATOS EN MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

[image: Datos solicitados para base de datos]

No he podido formular la base de datos, y la verdad se me esta complicando un poco. Es un proyecto de una pagina web medica que solicita los siguientes datos

Comment: Y... por qué no puedes? qué has intentado? Comparte el código que estás utilizando y el(los), error(es) que te encuentras.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Aquí puedes encontrar ayuda a tus problemas, pero esta no es una web donde colocar los deberes para que te los resuelvan (como parece que es el caso). Como te han comentado, intenta resolver el problema, y si tienes dudas o errores, coloca lo que has hecho y detallla el error y te ayudaremos a continuar hasta resolverlo.

Comment: [Aquí tienes toda la documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)  sobre `CREATE TABLE`  y [aquí tienes un tutorial con ejemplos](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-create-table/). Partiendo de eso, desarrolla tu ejercicio y si no funciona, entonces agrega el código a la pregunta pulsando en [edit] y te ayudaremos con gusto. Aquí no haremos el ejercicio por ti.